# Is there a way to put javax.portlet.title elements in <h2> tags?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm currently writing a portlet which gets deployed into liferay.

I show the portlet's frame including its portlet-title element.
My problem is that I can't put any tags around this title element.
(I have a resource bundle attached to that portlet holding such an entry:
`javax.portlet.title=My fancy title without h2 tag`)

It would be nice to have exactly that title wrapped by a h2 tag.
Simply writing it into the resource bundle does not work, it seems that html is escaped.
Writing `javax.portlet.title`=`<h2>My fancy title</h2>` shows me exactly that string on the website.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The portlet title is displayed (and the frame surrounding the portlet) is generated in portlet.vm, which is a file located in your theme. There it's, by default, generated with <h1>

```
<h1 class="portlet-title">
    $theme.iconPortlet() <span class="portlet-title-text">$portlet_title</span>
</h1>
```

If you could inject <h2> the way you mention, it would result in <h1><h2>My fancy title</h2></h1> (ignoring the icon here) due to that template

So: I guess you have your own theme, go there, override the file given. It's short, you can intuitively find the code you need to change there without problems.